# Virtual display and output on amdgpu drivers

Tags: linux, xorg, vnc, virtual-desktop, xorg.conf

My goal is to use a laptop as a screen for my main laptop through VNC. For that I need to create a virtual output (as the main laptop has only one HDMI that is connected to another display). I've read that it is only possible with a specific Intel driver ([#1](https://github.com/kbumsik/VirtScreen/issues/16#issuecomment-420711627), [#2](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=203339)), but all of these discussions are pretty old, I hope something has changed since then.

So what I want is: create virtual outputs on amdgpu with the only HDMI port in my laptop occupied.

Answer (score 0):

Posting an answer long after the setup is taken apart. Achieved it by creating virtual monitors using a virtual display driver on Windows 10. Then used Sunshine to host the virtual display and on the other laptop, Moonlight to view it.